# hbase-client 2.0.x error

Tags: java, maven, hbase, hbase-client

I'm trying to connect to a remote hbase server using the hbase-client java API.
So far i've been able to make it work with the hbase-client version 1.3.1. But to resolve a dependency conflict with gRPC i'm trying to make use of the hbase-client versoin 2.0.x.

I'm getting this error when i try to `admin.tableExists(tableName) in hbase java client versions 2.0.x.

But most of the other data persisting APIs work as usual. Could this be due to dependency issue or a version mismatch with the server.

Any suggestions to resolve the issue is very much appreciated.

> Hbase Server version :  1.2.4

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family table does not exist in region hbase:meta,,1.1588230740 in table 'hbase:meta', {TABLE_ATTRIBUTES => {IS_META => 'true', coprocessor$1 => '|org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.MultiRowMutationEndpoint|536870911|'}, {NAME => 'info', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '10', IN_MEMORY => 'true', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', CACHE_DATA_IN_L1 => 'true', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '8192', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.checkFamily(HRegion.java:7752)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.get(HRegion.java:6800)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.get(RSRpcServices.java:2032)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:33644)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2180)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:108)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException.instantiateException(RemoteWithExtrasException.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteWithExtrasException.java:83)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.makeIOExceptionOfException(ProtobufUtil.java:279)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.handleRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:266)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RegionServerCallable.call(RegionServerCallable.java:128)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:395)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:369)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.getTableState(MetaTableAccessor.java:1101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:419)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin$6.rpcCall(HBaseAdmin.java:443)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin$6.rpcCall(HBaseAdmin.java:440)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallable.call(RpcRetryingCallable.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:3094)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:3086)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:440)
        at com.stl.ecg.datacollection_ingestor.manager.DatabaseCreater.createDataTable(DatabaseCreater.java:24)
        at com.stl.ecg.datacollection_ingestor.config.HBaseConfig.getHBaseConnection(HBaseConfig.java:35)
        at com.stl.ecg.datacollection_ingestor.config.HBaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9dc49d56.CGLIB$getHBaseConnection$0(<generated>)
        at com.stl.ecg.datacollection_ingestor.config.HBaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9dc49d56$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9775ca2d.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
        at com.stl.ecg.datacollection_ingestor.config.HBaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9dc49d56.getHBaseConnection(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at com.stl.ecg.datacollection_ingestor.Main.main(Main.java:16)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException): org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family table does not exist in region hbase:meta,,1.1588230740 in table 'hbase:meta', {TABLE_ATTRIBUTES => {IS_META => 'true', coprocessor$1 => '|org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.MultiRowMutationEndpoint|536870911|'}, {NAME => 'info', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '10', IN_MEMORY => 'true', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', CACHE_DATA_IN_L1 => 'true', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '8192', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.checkFamily(HRegion.java:7752)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.get(HRegion.java:6800)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.get(RSRpcServices.java:2032)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:33644)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2180)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:108)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.onCallFinished(AbstractRpcClient.java:387)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.access$100(AbstractRpcClient.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$3.run(AbstractRpcClient.java:410)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$3.run(AbstractRpcClient.java:406)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.callComplete(Call.java:103)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.setException(Call.java:118)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcDuplexHandler.readResponse(NettyRpcDuplexHandler.java:161)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcDuplexHandler.channelRead(NettyRpcDuplexHandler.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

POM is as below,

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--AMQP-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Kafka-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Actuater to get service health information-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!--HBase-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-gcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Recommended for object auto-configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-auth-library-credentials</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>21.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
            <classifier>${os.detected.classifier}</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repository.spring.snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <extensions>
            <extension>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0.Final</version>
    </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>
```

Comment: Any solutions to this @Nowa?

Comment: Well, I figured out that it happened for me when the region for the table was offline for some weird reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-19145
Check this issue out for details.

The basic issue is, as the link says, "The main reason is in HBase 2.x, the table state is kept in meta. Therefore 2.x client will always go ask for table state from meta on the server, but 1.x server does not have it in meta."

Answer (score 3):

The result is the hbase server version and the hbase-client version inconsistency

Comment: This isn't much of an answer, can you elaborate / explain how to fix it?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case. But is there any documented evidence/proof to say that client and server versions of hbase need to be consistent?

Comment: @NowaConcordia were you able to find proof on this one ?

Comment: @Sukhmeet Singh not a proof as such. But as a rule of thumb, HBase server is backward compatible while client is not. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For me the reason was that i talked to a 1.4.9 database with the 2.x client libraries.
I fixed it by using the correct version of the client, e.g.

```
compile("org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:1.4.9")
```

for gradle.

In your case, you need to update your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case. But is there any documented evidence/proof to say that client and server versions of hbase need to be consistent?

Answer (score 2):

You can use hbase-client 1.x to solve the corresponding problem, but it is implemented by **blocking IO, and the performance is very poor in concurrent scenarios.**
The cause of `NoSuchColumnFamilyException` is thrown by the `MateAccess.tableExists ()` method (the metadata of this method query comes from zookeeper, but the metadata of hbase1.x is not stored in zookeeper)
I used **hbase2.x's asynchronous** query method to solve this problem:

```
    AsyncConnection client = ConnectionFactory.createAsyncConnection(hbaseConf).get() ;
   String hBaseTab = "test";
   TableName tableName = TableName.valueOf(hBaseTab); 
   AsyncTable<AdvancedScanResultConsumer> htabe = client.getTable(tableName); //AsynHTable 
    Scan request = getUserReq(); // your request 
    htable.scan(request,new AdvancedScanResultConsumer() {
                                @Override
                                public void onError(Throwable error) {
                                    log.error("HBase scan failed.cause:",error);
                                    //====java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
                                    future.tryFail(error);
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete() {
                                    future.tryComplete(arr);
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onNext(Result[] results, ScanController controller) {
                                        arr.addAll(Arrays.asList(results));
                                        //over max size
                                        if (arr.size() >= request.getLimit()){
                                            controller.terminate();
                                        }
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: Supplement:
In high concurrency scenarios(10K QPS + ), the synchronous method consumes twice as much time as the asynchronous method.  Like is [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ordiychen/study_notes/master/res/image/node_image/img20200409102645.png)

Comment: Asynchronous client seems the better way to go. Customization are possible using BufferedMutator etc when more control is needed.

Comment: Also @Ordiy, this solution works because Asynchronous client doesn't use the specific MetaAccess methods?