# Unable to query hbase table using api

Tags: hbase

I have a valid HBase table. I can see its description from `hbase shell.

```
hbase(main):004:0> describe 'hbase_lookup'
Table hbase_lookup is ENABLED                                                                                                                                                                                                                
hbase_lookup                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
COLUMN FAMILIES DESCRIPTION                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
{NAME => 'cf1', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', VERSIONS => '1', IN_MEMORY => 'false', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '
65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}
```

However, when I try to access this, I am getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family table does not exist in region hbase:meta,,1.1588230740 in table 'hbase:meta', {TABLE_ATTRIBUTES => {IS_META => 'true', coprocessor$1 => '|org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.MultiRowMutationEndpoint|536870911|'}, {NAME => 'info', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '10', IN_MEMORY => 'true', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', CACHE_DATA_IN_L1 => 'true', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '8192', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.checkFamily(HRegion.java:7819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.get(HRegion.java:6855)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.get(RSRpcServices.java:2010)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:33644)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:163)
```

Comment: Can you provide a `get` or a `scan` that you're trying to execute?

Comment: I have changed the maven dependency to be exactly same as hbase version. And now it works. The error is misleading from hbase. It should throw some other exception rather than NoSuchColumFamily exception.

Comment: Yeah, that error actually refers to `hbase:meta`, which means you had smth similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46468430/hbase-client-2-0-x-error